# How to query many to many relations with Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have this many to many relation in Postgres:

```js
// migrations/2020_create_initial_tables.js

exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('students', function(table) {
      table.increments('id').primary()
      table
        .string('email')
        .unique()
        .index()
      table.string('password')
    })
    .createTable('courses', function(table) {
      table.increments('id').primary()
      table.string('title').notNullable()
      table.text('description')
    })
    // A student can enroll many courses
    // A course can have many students
    .createTable('student_courses', function(table) {
      table.increments('id').primary()
      table
        .integer('student_id')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('students')
      table
        .integer('course_id')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('courses')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      throw err
    })
  // .finally(() => knex.destroy());
}

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .dropTableIfExists('students')
    .dropTableIfExists('courses')
    .dropTableIfExists('student_courses')
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
      throw err
    })
}
```

I need to show a student's enrolled courses. 
How do I query (all/an array of) `courses` by `student.id`?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Stack: TypeScript, knex@v0.20.12, Postgres@12-alpine, pg@v7.18.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const coursesOfSingleStudent = await knex('courses').whereIn('id',
   knex('student_courses').select('course_id').where('student_id', studentId)
)
```

Though you might be better off using objection.js which allows you to declare relation mappings and then query directly:

```
const studentWithCourses = await Student.query().findById(studentId).withGraphFetched('courses');
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but there's literally no documentation on how to e.g. create a proper migration for m-to-m relations. 

In general, docs for knex & objection are not very good, to put it gently. 

Do you have a good example on how to create proper m-to-m relations with migration & then use it with objection, or maybe, generate migration based on Objection models?

Comment: The same way that you would do migrations with SQL... If you mean how to create tables and foreign keys etc. you need to add a separate question about it (or just search an answer from SO).  No way to generate migrations based on DB models. Objection actually has pretty good docs compared to standards of  JS world... knex not so much.